# lapply: extract specific element

Tags: r

I have a list of subsets obtained through:

`lapply(1:5, function(x) combn(5,x))`

I would like to extract a specific vector from this list. For example, the 16th element of this list, which is (1,2,3). Any hints? Thanks.

The command produces all the subsets of (1,2,3,4,5), which is a list of 2^5=32 subsets. The 16th being (1,2,3). I want to know how to extract this by using its position (16th).

Comment: In the example, there are only 5 list elements.

Comment: If `lst` is the object name, `lst[[3]][,1]`

Comment: @akrun There are 32 vectors.  The command produces all the subsets of (1,2,3,4,5), which is a list of 2^5=32 subsets. The 16th being (1,2,3). I want to know how to extract this by using its position (16th).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try by splitting (`split`) the matrix to a list of vectors for each list elements, concatenate `c` the output to flatten the list, and subset using the numeric index.

```
 lst2 <- do.call(`c`,lapply(lst, function(x) split(x, col(x))))
 lst2[[16]]
 #[1] 1 2 3
```

Or instead of splitting the matrix output, we could use the `FUN` argument within `combn` to create `list` and then concatenate `c` using `do.call`

```
 lst <- do.call(`c`,lapply(1:5, function(x) combn(5, x, FUN=list)))
 lst[[16]]
 #[1] 1 2 3
```

Or instead of `do.call(`c`,..)`, we can use (contributed by @Marat Talipov)

```
  lst <- unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) 
            combn(5, x, FUN=list)), recursive=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
 lst <- lapply(1:5, function(x) combn(5,x))
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: Another flavor of your solution would be to use `unlist(...,recursive=F)` instead of `do.call('c',...)`

Answer (score 1):

I would rather consider producing the right data instead of looping again on them :)

```
lst = Reduce('c', lapply(1:5, function(x) as.list(data.frame(combn(5,x)))))
> lst[[16]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Good point, I will take it into account. Symbolic upvote (I don't have enough reputation for an actual upvote).

Comment: It's also good to simplify things and offer alternative ;) In the final code it makes clearly more sense to generate properly data from the beginning!